# Import local image with FeedMe assumes wrong folderId

Tags: image, plugin-feedme, import, assets-field

I am importing Entries from Google Spreadsheets and I have a column in my spreadsheet containing the filename of an image already existing in Craft.

The import itself works, but images are not found / not selected in the asset field.

In the logs I can see that the image query is wrong, it looks like that:

*Search for existing asset with query* `{"siteId":1,"status":null,"folderId":1,"kind":null,"limit":"9","filename":"test-container-3.png","includeSubfolders":true}`

The `filename` is correct, however the `folderId` is wrong, it should be `2`.

I tried working with plain filenames like "test-container-3.png", I also tried prepending an alias pointing to the correct folder (absolute URL) like "@importImages/test-container-3.png". Made no difference.

How does FeedMe decide to use `folderId 1` in its query? How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the problem / solution myself:

- I have 2 file volumes in my Craft installation (documents, images)
- The asset field I am trying to fill via FeedMe is in its configuration limited to the "images" file volume, but the default location for uploads is (erroneously) configured in the documents share.
- In this case, FeedMe is determining the folderId from the default location for uploads.
- The same thing happens, if all volumes are configured for selection, so in my eyes this is a bug, which I filed here (https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/833)
- So after changing the default upload location of my asset field to be where my files are actually located ("images" volume), everything works.
- The column value needs to be the filename only, no alias or anything else prepended.

Comment: Did you find the solutions? I am facing the same issue. I have created a new folder named property_image in the web folder.

In the CSV I have used -|- for delimiter multiple images.  

CSV Column image has a value 

property_images/100339EED16_1.png-|-property_images/100339EED16_2.png

Entry created successfully but without Images.

If I use https://xxy.com/property_images/100339EED16_1.png-|-https://xxy.com/property_images/100339EED16_2.png then it importing images too but i have around 100K entries so its taking too much time too import

Comment: There is no fix from P&T, it seems the plugin is not well maintained. But as written above, I solved it by changing the default upload location for my import.

Comment: Actually, I am uploading entries's Assets from the temporary folder. once importing is finished, I will remove that folder. this will run on a daily basis Let me know if you have any solutions. Thanks